# Handling FCM Notification while running and killed

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am searching for a pattern for handling fcm notifications while the app is running, in background or killed.

Our app features a login process and therefor when the app is not launched, the notification needs to open the launcher, but when the app is running i want to just push an activity when the user clicks the notification.

So the best way i guess would be an ContentIntent that gets either delivered to the top most Activity in the Stack or delivered to the Launch-Activity.

My current code always relaunches the app with a TaskStackBuilder no matter if the app is running or not.

A sample of my code:

```
resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyProfileActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra(ActivityUtil.KEY_IMAGE_URL, SharedPref.getUserImage(this));
resultIntent.putExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationID);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(SetDetailReworked.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "...")
            .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromUrl(images[UI.GetDensityInt(this)]))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bar_icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.push_notification_Title))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

Notification not = builder.build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(ID, not);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your MyProfileActivity's launchMode as singleInstance in androidManifest,

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MyProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

and it will not relaunches your background activity when user clicks the notification. Instead, MyProfileActivity's onNewIntent will be fired.